# Meteor SignUps Forbidden on Accounts.createUser

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I'm getting the error "SignUps Forbidden" when i try to create a user account. Any ideas why?

My packages:

useraccounts:materialize
materialize:materialize
accounts-password
accounts-facebook
service-configuration
accounts-google
accounts-twitter
kadira:blaze-layout
msavin:mongol
kadira:flow-router
kevohagan:sweetalert

Client Code:

```
Template.register.events({
    'click #register-button': function(e, t) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // Retrieve the input field values
        var email = $('#email').val(),
            firstName = $('#first-name').val(),
            lastName = $('#last-name').val(),
            password = $('#password').val(),
            passwordAgain = $('#password-again').val();


        // Trim Helper
        var trimInput = function(val) {
            return val.replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g, "");
        }
        var email = trimInput(email);

        // If validation passes, supply the appropriate fields to the
        // Meteor.loginWithPassword() function.
            Accounts.createUser({
                email: email,
                firstName: firstName,
                lastName: lastName,
                password: password
            }, function(error) {
                if (error) {
                    return swal({
                    title: error.reason,
                    text: "Please try again",
                    showConfirmButton: true,
                    type: "error"
                });
                } else {
                    FlowRouter.go('/');
                }
            });

        return false;
    }
});
```

Server code

```
 Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
    user.profile = options.profile || {};

    user.profile.firstName = options.firstName;
    user.profile.lastName = options.lastName;

    user.profile.organization = ["Org"];
    user.roles = ["User"];

    return user;
});
```

UPDATE:

Here is a [link](https://github.com/MMrj9/hubapp) to the repo

The problem seems to be on .....meteor\local\build\programs\server\packages. If i switch the value to false it's useless because it resets on every build.

```
// Client side account creation is disabled by default:
// the methos ATCreateUserServer is used instead!
// to actually disable client side account creation use:
//
//    AccountsTemplates.config({
//        forbidClientAccountCreation: true
//    });

Accounts.config({
  forbidClientAccountCreation: true
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to remove the useraccounts:materialize in order to solve this problem

Comment: I don't think this solves the problem. What if you want to use `useraccounts:materialize` ?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that the current accepted answer is the right one.

If you want to keep your packages yet override the setting you can change the value of `Accounts._options.forbidClientAccountCreation` in your code.

Set it to `true` if you want to prevent the account creation, or to `false` otherwise.

Comment: I just verified this answer, with one change (false not true), for this fixed it in my server startup:

Accounts._options.forbidClientAccountCreation = false;

Comment: Thanks @Tomachi, I edited the answer with the boolean values.